# How to see queries run by Django ORM?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-orm

I have `DEBUD = True` in `settings.py` file. I have `MySQL` database configured with django. I have a `Course` model in `courses/models.py`. In `courses/views.py`, I have:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def courses_list(request):
  courses = Course.objects.all()
  serializer = CourseSerializer(courses, many=True)
  return Response(serializer.data)
```

Now, If I make request from Postman to hit this view, I think some query like `SELECT * FROM COURSES` must be executed. How to see which queries has been executed when I make a request to some backend URL?

I have also tried `from django.db import connection` as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running), but got empty array like this:

```
>>> from django.db import connection
>>> connection.queries
[]
```

Please, help me achieve what I want to.

Comment: If you run this in a separate shell, then this will of course not contain the queries of *another* running program. The answer deals with queries you perform in the shell itself.

Comment: Oh, I see. How should I do it then? If in any file, then how? Can you please help? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run this in a separate shell, then this will of course not contain the queries of *another* running program. The answer deals with queries you perform in the shell itself.

For example if you would use:

```
>>> print(Course.objects.all())
>>> from django.db import connection
>>> connection.queries
```

It would show a query, since you forced the evaluation of a `QuerySet` in *that* shell.

You can make use of a package like [**`django-sqlprint-middleware`**](https://pypi.org/project/django-sqlprint-middleware/) to print queries. So you install it, for example in the local environment with:

```
pip install django-sqlprint-middleware
```

and then add this piece of middleware in the `MIDDLEWARE` setting of the `settings.py`:

```
# settings.py

MIDDLEWARE = (
    # …,
    'django_sqlprint_middleware.SqlPrintMiddleware',
    # …,
)
```

This will *only* print the queries when `DEBUG` or `TESTING` are set to `True`. I would however advise not to use this on production anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Run your Django app like this:

```sh
./manage.py shell_plus --print-sql
```

and you suppose to see the queries printed in this shell